# "REHAN" and "RIHAN" has the same meaning in arabic context?

Tags: arabic

As salam wa alaikum,

In the Arabic context is it ok if we spell as "RIHAN" or "REHAN"?  Are both same meaning  in arabic context ?

Comment: "I want to name my brother" is not really your question. So I changed the title.

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE! We suggest you read the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq).  You may like to add an Ayah which has that word in it, you may also wish to see this, Insha'Allah it will be of benefit http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11/should-we-allow-questions-regarding-the-arabic-language

Answer (score 1):

There are two words in Arabic that are roughly spelled the same but are not the same. One is Rehan(Arabic: الریحان) and means basil in English. It's written with an *H*(Arabic: ح) in the middle and can be spelled either with an *i* or an *e*, but the *e* one seems to be more common. The other one is Rayan or Rayyan(Arabic:الریان), which means the source of irrigation. This can also refer to باب الریان, which means *one of the Gates of Janna*.<sup>1</sup>

Answer (score 1):

ریحان with a Fathah on the Raa' (ر) may at times refer to an herb called Basil.  At other times it refers to Rizq/رزق the bounty/sustenance of Allah to us.  It would seem you are looking for the best and most closest transliteration of the Arabic word, it would be Raihaan.  Sources: Maqayees Al Lugha مقاييس اللغة

You may also wish to consult an Arabic dictionary, like Al Qamoos Al Muheet (القاموس المحيط) to see the meanings of single words.

Answer (score 0):

They have the same meaning;

The faseeh correct spelling/pronounce is Rihan (RaI-han)
Some Arabic countries (like Egypt) pronounce it (slang) as Rehan (Ree-han)